# Win10 IoT - RaspBerry Pi2: ValueChanged not called when GPIO change

Tags: .net, events, raspberry-pi, gpio, windows-10-iot-core

I'm testing Win10 IoT on my Rpi2, with the following code:

```
private void InitializeInterrupt()
{
    GpioController gpioController = GpioController.GetDefault();
    GpioPin buttonPin = gpioController.OpenPin(24);
    _ledPin= gpioController.OpenPin(25);

    buttonPin.SetDriveMode(GpioPinDriveMode.InputPullUp);
    _ledPin.Write(buttonPin.Read());

    _ledPin.SetDriveMode(GpioPinDriveMode.Output);
    buttonPin.ValueChanged += OnButtonChanged;
}

private void OnButtonChanged(GpioPin sender, GpioPinValueChangedEventArgs args)
{
    //I know the condition is inversed, I want the led UP when the button is not closed
    _buttonFeedbackPin.Write(args.Edge != GpioPinEdge.RisingEdge ? GpioPinValue.High : GpioPinValue.Low);
}
```

The issue is that my OnButtonChanged is not called. I basically just wire my GPIO button to the Ground(also tested to VCC).

The weird thing is that if I call manually the `buttonPin.Read()`, I got the correct `GpioPinValue` inside, so what could I've done wrong

Comment: I'll go on a limb and say that `InputPullUp` isn't supported according to the docs. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.gpio.gpiopindrivemode.aspx Might be why the event isn't firing.  Can you verify with `GetDriveMode()`?  Can you also try a different physical pin?

Comment: Not fun to put some enum that cannot be used :'(. Already tried another pin. I will try with the GetDriveMode as soon as I get my Pi setup. How should I use the GPIO as Input mode then?

Comment: Just use the defined `Input` enum.  I agree that it blows they put in enum values that are "Not supported", but I think M$ is future-proofing the API to  an extent, especially if they want Win10 IOT to run on a variety of devices.  Also, this IS a preview build, so hopefully they'll support built in pull ups / downs..

Comment: Yes, but do I have to change something to my schematic?

Comment: @J4N managed to get it to work? Because I have exactly the same issue, only on a newer build of win10 iot http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43763366/valuechanged-not-firing-with-c-sharp-win10-iot