# ValueChanged not firing with C# Win10 Iot

Tags: c#, event-handling, gpio, windows-10-iot-core

It seems exactly like [Win10 IoT - RaspBerry Pi2: ValueChanged not called when GPIO change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31445905/win10-iot-raspberry-pi2-valuechanged-not-called-when-gpio-change)
I have a raspberry pi 2 with win10 IoT (creator version) and have this C# code:

```
public sealed class StartupTask : IBackgroundTask
{
    private const int SENSOR_PIN = 17;
    private GpioPin pinSensor;

    public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {
        taskInstance.Canceled += TaskInstance_Canceled; // "destructor"

        var gpio = GpioController.GetDefault();

        if (gpio != null)
        {
            pinSensor = gpio.OpenPin(SENSOR_PIN); // also tried with GpioSharingMode.SharedReadOnly

            var r = pinSensor.Read(); // works and changes if sensor changes. Verified with quickwatch

            pinSensor.SetDriveMode(GpioPinDriveMode.Input);
            pinSensor.DebounceTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(20);

            pinSensor.ValueChanged += PinIn_ValueChanged;
        }
    }

    private void PinIn_ValueChanged(GpioPin sender, GpioPinValueChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        // never gets hit... 
    }

    private void TaskInstance_Canceled(IBackgroundTaskInstance sender, BackgroundTaskCancellationReason reason)
    {
        pinSensor.Dispose();
    }
}
```

led on sensor and quickwatch say the GpioPinValue does alternate between high and low... so should get hit...

When I retrieve the drive mode after setting it to input. It tells me it actually is set to input:

```
var dm = pinSensor.GetDriveMode();
```

as was suggested in the comment of the linked stack overflow issue. So what am I doing wrong? And more important: why?

Comment: Does `GpioController.GetDefault` return the same instance every time or does it construct a new instance every time and return it?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I have it in my `public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)` as a local variable. It always have 54 pins available each run. Raspberry pi 2 has only 1 gpio, so I expected it to be the same every time. I do not see a unique ID in the object to verify it is the same or something. It is a background application, so I expected it to keep running in the background. Or do I need something to keep the program open and running?

Comment: Have you added `var deferval = taskInstance.GetDeferral();` in `Run()` ?

Comment: Thank you @RitaHan-MSFT that is the correct answer. Please post it as answer so I can mark it as solved and award you with the rep points :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When the Run method ends, unless a deferral object is created, the
>   Background Application ends. The common practice, for asynchronous
>   programming is to take a deferral like this:

```
var deferval = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
```

Ref:[Developing Background Applications](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/docs/backgroundapplications)