# Raspberry 3 push button in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, button, raspberry-pi3

I'm trying out C# for Raspberry through Visual Studio and windows 10 IoT. Just took me an eternity to make everything work, but I slowly got there. I got my leds workings following their outdated 2 years old tutorials. I'm now trying to add a button to my breadboard to turn the leds on and off... Sadly, This doesn't work at all. It's like ValueChanged is never triggered.

I followed this guide: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/samples/pushbutton

My button is wired like: 1 pin directly to ground and the other one to GPIO18 (Pin 12)

Before thequestion comes, yes I did try using GPIO5 too. I just went back to GPIO18 as it was working on my python script before.

This is the code I'm trying to run, but having button problems (leds are fine):

```
public sealed class StartupTask : IBackgroundTask
{
    private GpioController gpio = GpioController.GetDefault();
    private GpioPin pinRed;
    private GpioPin pinBlue;
    private GpioPin pinButton;
    private GpioPinValue pinValue;
    private const int BLUE_PIN = 19;
    private const int RED_PIN = 26;
    private const int BUTTON_PIN = 18;

    public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("initialising");

        InitGpio();
        if (pinRed != null)
        {
            pinValue = GpioPinValue.High;
            pinRed.Write(pinValue);
            pinBlue.Write(pinValue);
        }
    }

    private void InitGpio()
    {
        gpio = GpioController.GetDefault();

        if (gpio == null)
        {
            pinRed = null;
            pinBlue = null;
            pinButton = null;
            Debug.WriteLine("Failed starting GPIO");
            return;
        }

        pinValue = GpioPinValue.Low;

        pinRed = gpio.OpenPin(RED_PIN);
        pinRed.Write(pinValue);
        pinRed.SetDriveMode(GpioPinDriveMode.Output);

        pinBlue = gpio.OpenPin(BLUE_PIN);
        pinBlue.Write(pinValue);
        pinBlue.SetDriveMode(GpioPinDriveMode.Output);

        pinButton = gpio.OpenPin(BUTTON_PIN);
        if (pinButton.IsDriveModeSupported(GpioPinDriveMode.InputPullUp))
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Is supported");
            pinButton.SetDriveMode(GpioPinDriveMode.InputPullUp);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Not supported");
            pinButton.SetDriveMode(GpioPinDriveMode.Input);
        }

        pinButton.DebounceTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50);
        pinButton.ValueChanged += buttonValueChange;

        Debug.WriteLine("GPIO initialised");
    }

    private void buttonValueChange(GpioPin sender, GpioPinValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("here");
        if (e.Edge == GpioPinEdge.FallingEdge)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Button push");

            pinValue = (pinValue == GpioPinValue.Low) ? GpioPinValue.High : GpioPinValue.Low;
            pinRed.Write(pinValue);
            pinBlue.Write(pinValue);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Button release");
        }
    }
}
```

Yes, lots of debug lines, as I said, trying out C# on Raspberry (InputPullUp is supported). The "here" in buttonValueChange is never triggered. I did the exact same wiring setup on Python and it worked flawlessly on the same pins.

Comment: Just before `pinButton.DebounceTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50);` could you add something like `var dm = pinButton.GetDriveMode();` and check which drive mode is actually set?

Comment: Just checked, it returns: InputPullUp

Answer (score 0):

It is suggested here [ValueChanged not firing with C# Win10 Iot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43763366/valuechanged-not-firing-with-c-sharp-win10-iot) that "When the Run method ends, unless a deferral object is created, the Background Application ends."

As such you could try to add this line to your `Run` code:

```
var deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
```

And see if it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this doesn't solve the problem. In fact I got so tired about this that I tried python on Visual Studio and made a quick button project for my raspi under it and it works flawlessly, with the samepin layout.